# Как получить процент от BigInteger?

Tags: c#, .net, biginteger

```
private int GetCurrentPercentUL()
{
    var maxItem = 100153UL;
    var currentItem = 100150UL;
    return (int)(currentItem / (maxItem / 100M));
}

private int GetCurrentPercentBI()
{
    var maxItem = new BigInteger(100153);
    var currentItem = new BigInteger(100150);
    return (int)(currentItem / (maxItem / 100));
}
```

Был вариант с ulong и decimal (100M), работал вполне корректно. Потом пришлось увеличить числовой диапазон до BigInteger, и встала проблема с подсчетом процентов. Как правильно и красиво переделать метод GetCurrentPercentBI для корректной работы?

---

Upd:

```
private int GetCurrentPercentBI()
{
    var maxItem = new BigInteger(100153);
    var currentItem = new BigInteger(100150);
    var percent = (int)(currentItem / (maxItem / new BigInteger(100)));
    if (percent == 100 && maxItem > currentItem)
        percent = 99;
    return percent;
}
```

Есть такое решение, но по мне - оно некрасивое. Если есть более корректные варианты - напишите в ответах.

Comment: Вы теряете тип. Как вариант - приведите все числа к BigInt (а именно 100 поменять на `BigInteger(100)`),  а потом результат кастить в int.

Comment: @nick_n_a, нет, не помогло. Обратите внимание, что метод GetCurrentPercentUL возвращает 99, а метод GetCurrentPercentBI возвращает 100. Так же задейтствовать Math не представляется возможным из-за того, что она не поддерживает тип BigInteger.

Comment: `currentItem * 100 / maxItem`